# How does i2c standard or fast mode effect the output data rate of the sensor?

Tags: sensor, i2c, baudrate, data-rate

I am using BNO055 motion sensor supports standard mode 100kHz and fast mode 400kHz

but sensor specifies [following](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor)

Gravity Vector 100Hz

Euler Vector, 100Hz

Quaternion, 100Hz

Magnetic Field Strength Vector **(20Hz)**

How do they change from when 100kHz vs 400kHz?

What is the actual use of those two modes?

Comment: Why should they change? The Bus speed has nothing to do with the sensor. This sensor can be used on 100kHz I2C busses and on 400kHz busses as well. Its just the bus speed, not the sensor speed

Comment: @sgt_johnny so at 100Khz, i get 100Hz data as specified?

Comment: @sgt_johnny what is the use of those two modes ?

Comment: Yes you get 100Hz data. The speeds of the bus are compatible to 100kHz and 400kHz. Usually, I2C bus have more than one node, now imagine, you have a sensor that needes to be driven at 400kHz, but your sensor number two could not support 400kHz, it would not be usuable in this bus. Thats why the BNO55 supports both modes, to be compatible with both network speeds.

Comment: @sgt_johnny Don't answer questions in the comment section. There's a lot of resources in the help and meta explaining why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are completely unrelated. How fast you read the data does not change how often the device samples or updates the internal registers.

The reason for choosing 100 kHz or 400 kHz I2C has more to do with how fast you *want* to drive the bus, which in turn determines your required pull-up resistors depending on the length of the bus, number of other components, amount of data to transfer, etc.

Comment: what is the use of those two modes (fast and standard)?

Comment: @vassidefuk That would amount to a whole question on its own (which might already be answered on this site), but I tried to update my answer.

Comment: The point of those standards is the maximum speed. Some chips support only the oldest version, Standard Mode, up to 100 kHz bus clock. Some chips are capable of supporting the Fast Mode, up to 400 kHz. Standard Mode devices can't work at over 100 kHz but you can use all chips up to 100 kHz.

Comment: Now there are two completelty different answers I can see, which is correct?

Comment: @vassidefuk I don't think I can help you further then, I only see one answer. Maybe if you point out where the difference is.